# How to get BigQuery Storage Write API logs on a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-bigquery-storage-api

I am coding in Python a Cloud Function that writes data to BigQuery.
To bypass quota limits, I am trying to use the BigQuery Storage Write API to write my data, following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-batch).
The destination BigQuery table has Datetime columns but it seems to not be supported by protobuf so I use timestamps in my stream instead.

I am using cloud logging on Debug on my Cloud Function

```
logging_client = cloud_logging.Client()
logging_client.get_default_handler()
logging_client.setup_logging(log_level=logging.DEBUG)
```

When launching my Cloud Function, I get the following error in the function logs:
`google.api_core.exceptions.Unknown: None There was a problem opening the stream. Try turning on DEBUG level logs to see the error.`

How can I get the logs from the BigQuery Storage Write API on a Cloud Function?
Moreover, can Bigquery automatically convert timestamps to datetime during the insert?

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#data_type_conversions has details about the possible mappings between the protobuf types and the corresponding BigQuery types.

For the datetime case, it's probably simplest to use a string protobuf field, and encode the value as a [datetime literal](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#datetime_literals).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using a string instead of a timestamp seems to work much better. I still don't know how to display Storage Write API logs on Cloud Logging but my stream works now. I am batch loading data with the Storage Write API but I have noticed subsequent UPDATE queries fail due to 'streaming buffer' errors. Do you know if the Storage Write API streams data in tables even for batch loading?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It sounds like https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#use_data_manipulation_language_dml_with_recently_streamed_data may be of interest to you.